# Organizing and hosting static files (downloads) with Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

I am trying to re-organize our web server and segregate download-able files from the HTML/content of the site. I have setup a "data" directory like so:

```
/data
  /public
    /pdf, /image, /audio, etc...
  /protected
    /pdf, /image, /audio, etc...
```

So everything in /public is fully accessible, everything in /protected is behind ModAuth.

My question is, is there anyway to directly link files from within the "file-type" sub-directories? This would make all URLs of the form "/public/something.jpg" or "/private/mydoc.pdf" without the need for subdirectories in the URL. However, I still want to use the subdirectories for my own organization.

This is not a very big issue, just something I got curious about as I started working on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a job for `mod_rewrite`:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Or, perhaps more on SF:

[Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)

You'd have something along the lines of:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /public/(.*)\.jpg        /public/image/$1.jpg
RewriteRule /public/(.*)\.pdf        /public/pdf/$1.pdf
```

and so on, for however many types you have.